# Class that extends subclasses of another class?

Tags: java

Say you have a Base Class, Animal. This Animal class has various abstract and overridable methods.

You have a subclass, Cow, which extends Animal. This class implements and overrides some methods.

You have another subclass, Pig, which extends Animal. This class implements and overrides some methods differently.

Finally, you have the class Pet. This Pet class needs to override certain methods within the Animal class, while leaving the AI methods and such for the Cow and Pig untouched.

As a constraint, I can't change alter the Cow and Pig class. But, it would basically act like the Cow and the Pig were subclasses of Pet, which is a subclass of Animal.

Here is an example of what I am thinking of:

```
public abstract class Animal {
  public abstract void eat();
  public abstract void ai();
  public abstract void die();
  public abstract void dropLoot();
}

public class Cow {
  @Override
  public void eat(){//foo}
  @Override
  public void ai(){//bar}
  @Override
  public void die(){//fig}
  @Override
  public void dropLoot(){//this would run normally}
  public void moo(){
    //Method for Reason
  }
}

public class Pig {
  //Same thing here
}

public class Pet<T extends Animal> extends T //Just visual. This doesn't work {
  @Override
  public void die(){
    //extra logic
    base.die(); //Returns up to the cow or pig instance
  }
  @Override
  public void dropLoot(){//this runs instead of whatever is in Cow or Pig classes}
  
  //I can only override methods that exist in Animal class, so Cow.moo is out of reach
}
```

That is my idea, at least. Alternatively, Pet could be a wrapper that somehow redirects the desired methods to some other method.

```
public class Pet {
  Animal animal;

  @Override(animal.dropLoot()) //Hypothetical implementation that doesn't currently work
  public void HandleDropLoot(){
    //This runs instead of animal.dropLoot, acting as an override.
  }
}
```

The problem is, I can't alter Cow or Pig, so I can only add on to the code. Either of these would work for my case.

I tried finding a way to simply use (? extends Animal) during the extends, but that threw a compiler error.

I tried using Generics, but that also did not work. (i.e. Pet extends T)

I tried the idea of just having the Animal as a variable with Wrapping, but I still have the problem of overriding or redirecting the methods in the Animal class.

Comment: implement an interface

Comment: Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, so one major implementation is denied to you.  You could also inherit from say `Cow`, to make a `PetCow`.  You could employ a Strategy Pattern where certain behaviors inside `Animal` can be replaced, and use a `PetBehavior` on certain animals.  `Pet<T extends Animal>` and a `PetWrapper` seem the same idea to me, they're both wrappers.  There might be other ideas I can't think of right now...

Comment: (I think what Old Programmer is saying is that if you make `Pet` an interface, then you can use `class PetCow extends Cow implements Pet` and you can have both on the same class, without multiple inheritance.)

Comment: @markspace actually, Java does not support multiple inheritance of classes but it does support multiple inheritance of interfaces.

Comment: Weelll, that is commonly expressed as "doesn't support multiple inheritance."  What everyone means by "multiple inheritance" is that you can inherit state variables from more than one class, and that gets into the diamond problem.  No diamond problem = no multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Alternatively, Pet could be a wrapper that somehow redirects the desired methods to some other method.

This smells like a job for the [Decorator Pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=decorator%20pattern%20java). The idea is your `Pet` class both *is* and *has* an animal, so it can be used as an `Animal` but then delegate to the wrapped class when needed.

```
public class Pet extends Animal {
    private final Animal mDecoratedAnimal;

    public Pet(Animal animalToDecorate) {
        mDecoratedAnimal = animalToDecorate;
    }

    @Override
    public void ai() { mDecoratedAnimal.ai() } // Just delegate

    @Override void die() {
        // Extra logic
        mDecoratedAnimal.die();
    }

    @Override
    public void dropLoot(){
        // This runs instead of whatever is in Cow or Pig classes}
    }
}
```

Then when you need to use it:

```
Animal cow = new Cow();
Animal pig = new Pig();
Animal petCow = new Pet(cow);
Animal petPig = new Pet(pig);

// Use petCow and petPig like any other animal:
petCow.ai() // Does Cow AI
petPig.ai() // Does Pig AI
petCow.dropLoot() // Does custom pet loot dropping
petPig.dropLoot() // Does custom pet loot dropping
petCow.die() // Does pet stuff then cow dies
petPig.die() // Does pet stuff then pig dies
```

Comment: Changed it a little bit to work for my situation. Thanks a lot for your help!